# How to install grub Ubuntu 14.04?

Tags: grub2

I installed Windows8.1 and Ubuntu 14.04 but when boot up its only take Ubuntu not take Windows. I also try this sudo apt-get install grub. Its not take.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I repair grub? (How to get Ubuntu back after installing Windows?)](http://askubuntu.com/questions/88384/how-can-i-repair-grub-how-to-get-ubuntu-back-after-installing-windows)

Answer (score 0):

open a terminal and use this code

```
sudo grub-install /dev/sda
```